# Printing system time in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I want to print out current time in my 8086 program, but why does it only print weird characters?

Also, the CH value is 15 and CL is 33, when the time in my system is 9:50.

```
org 100h   

data segment
hour db " "
min db " "
data ends

printf MACRO str
    lea dx, str
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
endm

code segment

start:

mov ah, 2Ch
int 21h    

mov hour, CH
mov min, CL 

printf hour
printf min

ret
```

Comment: Your hour/minute values are integers. `int 21h / ah=9` expects an address to a _string_.

Comment: 15h is the hexadecimal value of 21 (the hour) and 33h  is the hexadecimal value of 51 (the minute). To convert the hexadecimal or binar values into decimal numbers, there will be a lot of examples in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

`.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
    DISP DB "24-HOUR -->  "
    HR DB ?,?,' : '
    MIN DB ?,?,' HH:MM ',10,13,'$'
.CODE
START:
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV AH,2CH
    INT 21H
    MOV AL,CH
    AAM
    ADD AX, 3030H
    MOV HR, AH
    MOV HR+1, AL
    MOV AL,CL
    AAM
    ADD AX, 3030H
    MOV MIN, AH
    MOV MIN+1,AL
    LEA DX,DISP
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    INT 3
END START
.END`